# Swift static var in switch case

Tags: swift, switch-statement, static-variables

`switch-case` for comparing `static var`s isn't working as expected. However, specifying a type or comparing directly works. Please see below:

```
class AnimalHelper {
    func loadAnimal(_ animal: Animal) {

        // Doesn't compile
        switch animal {
            case .squirrel, .deer: loadGrass()
            case .dolphin: return // not implemented
            default: loadMeat()
        }

        // Direct comparison works
        if animal == .squirrel || animal == .deer {
            loadGrass()
        } else if animal == .dolphin {
            return // not implemented
        } else {
            loadMeat()
        }

        // Specifying the type explicitly also works
        switch animal {
            case Animal.squirrel, Animal.deer: loadGrass()
            case Animal.dolphin: return // not implemented
            default: loadMeat()
        }
    }

    func loadGrass() {}
    func loadMeat() {}
}

class Animal {
    let id = 6 // Will be generated
    let hasFourLegs = true
    let numberOfEyes = 2
    // ... //

    static var squirrel: Animal { return .init() }
    static var dolphin: Animal  { return .init() }
    static var puma: Animal { return .init() }
    static var deer: Animal { return .init() }
}

extension Animal: Equatable {
    public static func ==(lhs: Animal, rhs: Animal) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
```

I'm sure something about the above isn't quite right because of which I'm getting the following compilation errors:

```
Enum case 'squirrel' not found in type 'Animal'
Enum case 'deer' not found in type 'Animal'
Enum case 'dolphin' not found in type 'Animal'
```

Please let me know how is checking for equality in a `switch-case` is different from that in an `if` condition.

Comment: Update your question with the exact error message and point out the line causing the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift, `switch-case` may use several different rules to match the `switch`-value and the `case` labels:

- `enum` case matching

  In this case, you can use dot-leaded case labels, but unfortunately, your `Animal` is not `enum`.

  (This is not the same as *equality* below, as `enum` cases may have associated values.)
- pattern matching operator `~=`

  Swift searches an overload for the type of the `switch`-value and the type of `case`-label, if found, applies the operator and uses the the `Bool` result as indicating *matches*.
  For this purpose, Swift needs to infer the types of `case`-labels independent of the `switch`-value, thus Swift cannot infer the types of `case`-labels with dot-leaded notation.
- equality `==`

  When the `switch`-value is `Equatable`, Swift uses the equality operator `==` for matching the `switch`-value to the `case`-labels.

(There may be more which I cannot think of now.)

The detailed behavior is not well defined, but it's difficult for compilers to resolve two rules -- *pattern matching* and *equality*. (You may want to define custom matching with `~=` for `Equatable` types.)

So, **in Swift 3**, dot-leaded notation in the `case`-labels only works for `enum` types.

But, as far as I checked, Swift 4 have made it. Try Xcode 9 (currently the latest is beta 3), and your code would compile. This behavior may change in the release version of Xcode 9, but you know how to work around.